# MySQL max_allowed_packet Randomly Changes to 1024 Bytes

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I keep getting an odd issue where MySQL (5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) will randomly and unexpectedly change the max_allowed_packet to 1024 (when querying the max_allowed_packet variable in mysql client).

The MySQL configuration file (/etc/mysql/my.cnf) was left as is after the install except for the bind address being commented out to allow remote connections. The value for max_allowed_packet for both mysqld and mysql are set to 16M, and upon startup of mysql server (service mysql start), the value is 16777216 as expected.

I have looked through the mysql error log and the syslog, and have found nothing relating to a database crash or restart.

The database is running on a VPS with 4GB of memory with Ubuntu 14.04, and is used by a Java Spring Application.

Currently the application is still under development and is using the mysql root account, which will be changed after the root cause of this issue is found.

The Datasource and EntityManager in Spring is configure as follows:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("...");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setPackagesToScan("com.app.entity");
    emf.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    emf.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return emf;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

mysql-connector-java and commons-dbcp libraries are used for database interaction.

After much searching I found that in newer versions of mysql, it is not possible to change the session variable of max_allowed_packet as it is a read-only variable. This is why I am scratching my head trying to figure out how and why this variable can change if the value in my.cnf is set to 16M.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this issue has been re-occurring ever since our packets increased in size above 1024.

Comment: set global max_allowed_packet using java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686735/how-to-solve-packet-too-big-exception-xampp-mysql/46663770#46663770

Comment: set global max_allowed_packet using java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686735/how-to-solve-packet-too-big-exception-xampp-mysql/46663770#46663770

Answer (score 4):

You say "when querying the max_allowed_packet variable in mysql client". We take that to mean that you are running a query such as:

```
SELECT @@global.max_allowed_packet, @@session.max_allowed_packet;
```

And that's returning a result something like this:

```
@@global.max_allowed_packet  @@session.max_allowed_packet  
---------------------------  ----------------------------
                   16777216                      16777216
```

It is possible to dynamically modify the `max_allowed_packet` value (if the user has sufficient privileges).

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 33554432 ;
```

We can verify that the value of global variable is modified:

```
SELECT @@global.max_allowed_packet, @@session.max_allowed_packet;

@@global.max_allowed_packet  @@session.max_allowed_packet
---------------------------  ----------------------------
                   33554432                      16777216
```

The value of the *session* variable is initialized when the session starts (as I understand it) from the current value of the server (*global*) variable.

---

There are several "sections" in the my.cnf file. To set the *global* `max_allowed_packet` value for the server, the setting should appear under the `[mysqld]` section of the `my.cnf`.  (This could also be supplied as a parameter on the command line that starts mysql. But we don't do that, we just set it in the my.cnf file.)

> my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
...
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysqldump]
...
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

The setting of `max_allowed_packet` can also appear under other sections of `my.cnf`. The settings under the other sections don't affect the server. That same line can appear, for example, under the `[mysqldump]`, `[mysql]` and `[client]` sections.  (I don't have a good understanding of the behavior when `max_allowed_packet` appears under those other sections with values that differ from the setting under the `[mysqld]` section.)

---

I've never observed the kind of behavior you describe; your description is a bit lacking in terms of the *exact* statements you are executing, and the *exact* output being returned.

Comment: Thanks for your insight on this. I know the question was a little vague, but I managed to find the issue. Looking through the error logs I found a warning mentioning an unknown IP address had connected. Doing a lookup of the IP showed that it was located in another region. We promptly changed out database passwords because we were compromised.